# Ordenação: respostas ativas primeiro que resposta excluídas

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Tem como deixar as respostas ativas acimas das exclusões, alguns resposta que foram excluídas ficam primeiro e depois as respostas ativas, será que não seria melhor de cara as respostas ativas ?

Link: [Associação entre 2 tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21384/associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-2-tabelas)

Só lembrando que a partir da pontuação ai a ordenação funcionou, eu acredito que deveria ser automaticamente para baixo independente das outras respostas ativas!

Comment: Estranho, é para as excluídas ficarem no fim da lista, por qualquer um dos 3 critérios de ordenação (votos, data, atividade). Isso permanece mesmo se você atualiza a página?

Comment: Eu vi numa exclusão sua por isso a pergunta!!!

Comment: [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21420/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-if-e-substring-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-funcionando?answertab=votes#tab-top)? Pra mim aparece por último...

Comment: Achei: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21384/associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-2-tabelas @bfavaretto

Comment: Agora deram uma pontuação e ela subiu! @bfavaretto

Comment: Consegui reproduzir votando contra a outra resposta (já removi o voto) e ordenando por atividade. Muito estranho mesmo, tem cara de bug. Ou talvez seja intencional no caso da ordenação por atividade, não sei.

Comment: é eu percebi isso, não sei se você concordo layout ficaria estranho uma resposta excluída na frente das ativas ... bom é uma opinião!

Comment: Testei melhor na [votação do que é on-topic](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264), que tem várias respostas excluídas. O site só joga as excluídas pro fim se você ordena por votos (que é o default e o que eu mais uso). Se ordena por data ou atividade, as excluídas ficam na ordem natural. Você costuma ler as respostas com que ordenação? Acho que se você muda a ordenação uma vez, o sistema lembra disso e passa a te mostrar as respostas sempre nessa ordenação, em todas as perguntas. Lembrando que nem todos enxergam conteúdo excluído.

Comment: Ixe, agora eu não entendi nada, eu só abro a questão e vejo as respostas kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk não entendi mesmo!, mas, tudo bem

Comment: É assim: o "normal" é ordenar por votos, e a maioria das pessoas vê as respostas nessa ordem e nunca muda a ordenação. Mas se você mudar a ordenação uma vez em uma pergunta qualquer, daí pra frente o sistema continua te mostrando as respostas nessa nova ordenação em TODAS as perguntas (a não ser que você mude de volta para "votos"). É meio esquisito mesmo, mas deve ter sido isso que te fez perceber e estranhar que havia uma resposta excluída "fora do lugar".